# "Native Code" message in return of VueJS method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

when using the following code:
https://github.com/iamshaunjp/vuejs-playlist/blob/lesson-18/src/App.vue

My browser displays `function () { [native code] }` where it should display "heeey cowboy".

Any idea what's going on? I'm working from the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yP5Tu3S_FtU&index=18&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gQcYgjhBoeQH7wiAyZNrYa), using the CLI, and everything is identical to the provided files.

Comment: Show how you are calling whatever function should be saying "heeey cowboy".  You are likely missing either a `:`, some `()` or doing something to cause Vue to try to output a literal function as apposed to calling something.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You forgot the parenthesis mate:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ greeting() }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

The error is in `greeting`, you forgot to add these parenthesis after it `()`, that's how you call a [javascript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: Aha! Funny, in Vanilla I would have caught that. Sometimes, Vue does *not* require the parenthesis after a method call. Can you explain when/why that is?

Comment: Well, it's not about vue then it's about the function being a callback. What happens is you send your function to a parent function which runs it.

Comment: here's a brief on callbacks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Comment: I would set greeting to a data or computed prop and call a method whenever you need to change that value -- or better yet, make a reactive computed property (which will update only when it needs to). Prefer to use static variables or data/computed props whenever you can. When you use a method in your template, it will be called repeatedly as the page redraws and I think there are probably very few use cases where that's desirable

Answer (score 5):

#### methods: vs. computed:

In Vue 3, while refactoring parts of main.js into a template, I mistakenly copy/pasted `computed:` (properties) into `methods:` in myTemplate.js.

When I re-ran app, I saw:

```
function () { [native code] }
```

... instead of return values from functions.

After moving my computed properties from `methods:` into `computed:` section of my `app.component`, the template called the functions properly.

To use Computed Properties in Vue we don't need `()`, just like `get` methods.

```
app.component('your-template', {
    props: {
        someObject: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        /* METHODS WITH ARGUMENTS - callWith(args) */
    },
    computed: {
        /* PROPERTIES - call without () */

        lastUpdated() {
            let _date = new Date(this.bookshelf.modified)
            return _date.toLocaleString()
        },
    },
    template: 
        /*html*/
        `
        <h3>
            {{ someObject.name }}
        </h3>
        <div>Updated: {{ lastUpdated }}</div>
        `,
})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer just because it gives the solution and gives an explanation .

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was nothing wrong with my code. I just had to delete node_modules folder, rebuild the app, unregister the service worker, refresh the app and it started to work